# Table of Contents (TOC) missing after using CGContextDrawPDFPage

Tags: pdf, quartz-2d, tableofcontents

i am cocoa programer and using Quartz to draw pdf files, the original pdf has table of contents (TOC), but the result pdf lost TOC  after using following functions.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) 
{
   page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage (document, i);
   CGContextDrawPDFPage (myContext, page);
}
```

Am I doing wrong or how to keep TOC with Quartz? Any help would be appreciated. (english is not my native language, hope you can understand what i am asking...)

Answer (score 1):

Your code takes the pages content from the source file and draws them on a new document. This is the only content you can transfer from one document to another. The bookmarks (TOC), form fields, annotations, links in the source file cannot be copied to the new document. It is a limitation of the CoreGraphics API.
So if you need to modify an existing PDF file you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can the PDF Kit framework of Apple do it, or other third-party can do it with easier interface?